# Calling methods conditionally inside Angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a beginner to Angularjs, what I'm trying to do is call two different methods from a directive depending on the condition.

My work flow is

- I have a form in a directive
- When i try to add a new record via the form, function in the
  directive should call the `save()` method
- when I try to update a new record, function in the directive should
  call the `update` method

This is my current code

```
#new html form (calling the form directive)
<recipe-form recipeForm="recipeFormData" > </recipe-form>

#edit html form (calling the form directive)
<recipe-form recipeForm="recipeFormData" > </recipe-form>
```

So in my directive I have the following method

```
#form directive
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="$parent.Update()">
```

So what I want to do is, when the directive calls from the `#new` I want the method to be

```
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="$parent.Create()">
```

So what I want to do is, when the directive calls from the `#edit` I want the method to be

```
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="$parent.Update()">
```

I was trying to pass the method as a param, but for some reason it didn't work:

```
   #update form 
   <recipe-form recipeForm="recipeFormData" update="Update()"> </recipe-form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell how you distinguish between the two actions, but you can always specify the method in a boolean variable (that you specify as a directive attribute, or a controller's scope variable, etc... let's call it `updateMethod`) and use it like this:

```
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="updateMethod ? $parent.Update() : $parent.Create()">
```

---

Or even two separate forms (especially useful if the forms themselves are different):

```
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="$parent.Update()" ng-if="updateMethod">
```

and:

```
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="$parent.Create()" ng-if="!updateMethod">
```

---

The third option would be using a single submit function, but putting an if/else branching inside it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I went with the first option .. :) sorry for the late acceptance of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You actually pass the update method *result* by writing the `()` brackets, not its *reference*.

I advice you to pass your update / create function in your directive attributes. This way is more parametrable, and doesn't refer to `$parent` wich is not well isolated.

HTML:

```
<recipe-form custom-data="recipeFormData" method="create"></recipe-form>
<recipe-form custom-data="recipeFormData" method="update"></recipe-form>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.recipeFormData = { foo: 'bar' };

$scope.create = function (data) {
  // create something
}

$scope.update = function (data) {
  // update something
}
```

Directive :

```
app.directive('recipeForm', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'mySuperDirective.html',

    // creates an isolated scope
    scope: {
      customData: '=',
      method: '='
    }
  };
});
```

mySuperDirective.html :

```
<form ng-submit="method()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="customData.foo">
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```